# Does the dilogarithm function (which is multi-valued) have a single-valued inverse?

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse-function, polylogarithm, multivalued-functions, branch-points

The $p$-logarithm is defined for $|z|<1$ by

$$\text{Li}_p(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^p}$$

and defined elsewhere in $\mathbb C$ by analytic continuation, though it may be multi-valued, depending on the path of continuation.

For an integer $p<0$, the $p$-logarithm is a rational function, whose inverse is an algebraic function, which is multi-valued. For example,

$$\text{Li}_{-1}(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2},\qquad\text{Li}_{-1}^{-1}(z)=\frac{2z+1\pm\sqrt{4z+1}}{2z}.$$

For $p=0$ we have

$$\text{Li}_0(z)=\frac{z}{1-z},\qquad\text{Li}_0^{-1}(z)=\frac{z}{1+z}=-\text{Li}_0(-z),$$

and for $p=1$ we have a form of the ordinary logarithm, whose inverse is an entire function:

$$\text{Li}_1(z)=-\ln(1-z),\qquad\text{Li}_1^{-1}(z)=1-e^{-z}.$$

So, for $p<0$ the $p$-logarithm is single-valued while its inverse is multi-valued, for $p=0$ the $p$-logarithm and its inverse are both single-valued, and for some $p>0$ the $p$-logarithm is multi-valued while its inverse is single-valued.

This isn't much reason to expect the "pattern" to hold for all integers $p>0$. Nevertheless, I'd like to know if it does hold. There's a lot of information on polylogarithms on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), but I didn't see any obvious answer to this simple question: Is $\text{Li}_p^{-1}$ single-valued? Equivalently, is $\text{Li}_p$ injective?

("Injective" is usually defined for single-valued functions. Here it means, if $z_1\neq z_2$, then the sets $\text{Li}_p(z_1)$ and $\text{Li}_p(z_2)$ don't intersect.)

We may focus on the case $p=2$.

---

Let's consider the values of $\text{Li}_2(z)$ near the branch point $z=1$, or equivalently of $\text{Li}_2(1-z)$ near $z=0$, noting that $\text{Li}_2(1)=\pi^2/6$:

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\text{Li}_2(1-z)=\text{Li}_2(z)+\ln(z)\ln(1-z)$$

$$=\left(z+\frac{z^2}{4}+\frac{z^3}{9}+\cdots\right)-\ln(z)\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}+\cdots\right)$$

(throw away the higher powers of $z$ since $z\approx0$)

$$\approx z-z\ln(z)=z\big(1-\ln(z)\big)$$

(use $\ln(z)\approx-\infty$)

$$\approx z\big({-\ln(z)}\big)=-z\ln(z).$$

Now let $z=e^u$ where $\text{Re}(u)\approx-\infty$, so that $\ln(z)=u$ (as one of the possible values), and

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\text{Li}_2(1-e^u)\approx-ue^u.$$

This latter function is certainly not injective. For any $a\in\mathbb R$, there is a sequence of points $u_k\in\mathbb C$ with $\text{Re}(u_k)<a$, along a curve which is almost a vertical line, all having the same value of $u_ke^{u_k}$, and all having different values of $z_k=e^{u_k}$. I can see this by graphing and analyzing the level curves of $|ue^u|$ and $\arg(ue^u)$: if $u=x+yi$, these curves have the form $y=\pm\sqrt{C^2e^{-2x}-x^2}$ and $x=y\cot(D-y)$, respectively.

Can we use this to prove that $\text{Li}_2$ is not injective? Or is something lost in these approximations? What other methods can we use?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73515/inverse-of-the-polylogarithm. Alternatively one may see that $Li_2(x)$ is strictly increasing, and hence injective, by considering its derivative. This extends easily to all positive integers $p$.

Comment: I meant the complex dilogarithm, not the real dilogarithm.

Comment: Numerical computation suggests that $$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=-\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\log(1-\xi)}{\xi}\,\mathrm{d}\xi=\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x-z}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\log x\,\mathrm{d}x$$ defined for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(1,\infty)$ is indeed injective. However, its inverse function seems not extend to an entire function, since the images of some other branches of $\operatorname{Li}_2$ overlap.

Comment: $Li_2(z) = \frac{-\log(1-z)}{z}, Li_2(1-z)' = \frac{\log(z)}{1-z}$ gives that $Li_2(1-e^{2i\pi} z)'=Li_2(1- z)'+\frac{2i\pi }{1-z}$ so  $Li_2(1-e^{2i\pi} z)=Li_2(1- z)-2i\pi \log(1-z)$

Comment: @reuns - What's your point? It looks like you're showing that $\text{Li}_2$ is multi-valued. We already knew that.

Comment: The branch points (the monodromy) tell a lot about the inverse. For example the inverse of a function $f$ is periodic iff $f$ has a logarithmic branch point.

Comment: @reuns - I still don't see how this helps. We want to know whether $\text{Li}_2^{-1}$ has a branch point, but clearly $\text{Li}_2$ is not periodic. Or are you saying that $\text{Li}_2^{-1}$ is periodic?

Comment: Suppose that $f$ is analytic on a bounded domain $D$ and continuous on $\overline D$ and also that $\partial D$ is a Jordan curve. Then $f$ is injective on $\overline D$ iff $f$ maps $\partial D$ bijectively to a Jordan curve. This might make the problem easier, as we can take an arbitrarily large bounded domain and analyze the behavior of the polylogarithm only on the banks of the branch cut and on a large circle. (The fact that the derivative of the polylogarithm doesn't vanish doesn't guarantee global injectivity, as the example of $e^z$ shows.)

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Li}_2'(z)=\frac{-\log(1-z)}{z}$ doesn't vanish so any curve $\gamma:0\to ?$ along which (the continuation of) $\text{Li}_2(z)$ is analytic gives a curve $\text{Li}_2^{-1}(\gamma):0\to ?$ along which $\text{Li}_2^{-1}$ is analytic.

Next $\text{Li}_2'(z)=\frac{-\log(1-z)}{z}$ shows that $$\text{Li}_2(1-z)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\text{Li}_2(z)-\log(z)\log(1-z)$$
for $z\in (0,1)$ and it is meant the principal branch of each term.

Continuing analytically by starting at $1/2$ and rotating one time around $z=0$ we get a new branch

$$\text{Li}_2(1-z)^{new\ branch}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\text{Li}_2(z)-(\log(z)+2i\pi)\log(1-z)$$
analytic for $\Im(z)>0,|z|<1$.

This branch has a zero near $0.08+0.18 i$, and since $\text{Li}_2(0)=0$ too it means that  $\text{Li}_2^{-1}$ is multivalued, ie. there are some curves $\Gamma:0\to 0$ along which $\text{Li}_2^{-1}$ is analytic but not the same at its departure and arrival.

[image]

(it is the argument principle which proves that there is a zero on this plot)

Comment: The argument principle requires a continuous curve, not a sequence of hundreds of points/pixels. :) Of course we can get around this by appealing to continuity...

Answer (score 0):

There is a result of Lewis which shows that the polylogarithm is a convex univalent function.  So the answer is yes.

https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s2-27/3/435/828376?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: Real or complex?

Comment: Complex $z$ positive $s$.

Comment: I see no '$s$' defined anywhere on this page. And your answer contradicts the other answer, requiring some explanation.

Comment: Okay, from [your answer to the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4391189/472818), you're considering $\text{Li}_p(z)$ only on the unit disk $|z|<1$. The OP says $\text{Li}_p(z)$ is "defined elsewhere in $\mathbb C$". Still, this answer may be useful to someone.