# Finding an inverse for Clausen Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, inverse, inverse-function

##### General

**Question:** What does an inverse function for the [Clausen Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClausenFunction.html) look like?

**Background:** I'm doing some math with infinite series of trigonometric functions. I keep coming back to simplification in the form of clusen functions. The question then arose how to rearrange equations with them according to their argument or what their inverse function (as an equation) would look like, e.g. in a closed form or a series.

##### Clarification

When I talk about Clausen functions, I mean the functions defined by the series expansions:

$$
\begin{align*}
S_{k}\left( x \right) &= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\sin\left( n \cdot x \right)}{n^{k}} \right]\\
C_{k}\left( x \right) &= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\cos\left( n \cdot x \right)}{n^{k}} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

The following applies: $\left\{ x,\, k \right\} \in \mathbb{C}$

The whole thing then has the relation to the [polylogarithms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html):

$$
\begin{align*}
S_{k}\left( x \right) &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left[ \operatorname{Li}_{k}\left( e^{-x \cdot i} \right) - \operatorname{Li}_{k}\left( e^{x \cdot i} \right) \right] \cdot i\\ C_{k}\left( x \right) &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left[ \operatorname{Li}_{k}\left( e^{-x \cdot i} \right) + \operatorname{Li}_{k}\left( e^{x \cdot i} \right) \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

##### My Attempts

###### $1$ Research

Clausen functions aren't very common compared to other special functions like hypergeometric functions, so I've had trouble finding them. So I just wanted to work with a relation that contains better known functions, which here are the polylogarithms. The best thing I found for this was a question on this forum *[Inverse of the polylogarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73515/1103878)*. But that's where it stops again.

###### $2$ Polynomial Clusters

There are some relations given by:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{S_{1}}\left( \theta \right) &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \pi - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \theta\\
\operatorname{S_{3}}\left( \theta \right) &= \frac{1}{6} \cdot \pi^{2} \cdot \theta - \frac{1}{4} \cdot \pi \cdot \theta^{2} + \frac{1}{12} \cdot \theta^{3}\\
\operatorname{S_{5}}\left( \theta \right) &= \frac{1}{90} \cdot \pi^{4} \cdot \theta - \frac{1}{36} \cdot \pi^{2} \cdot \theta^{3} + \frac{1}{48} \cdot \pi \cdot \theta^{4} - \frac{1}{240} \cdot \theta^{5}\\
&\dots\\
\operatorname{C_{2}}\left( \theta \right) &= \frac{1}{6} \cdot \pi^{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \pi \cdot \theta + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \theta^{2}\\
\operatorname{C_{4}}\left( \theta \right) &= \frac{1}{90} \cdot \pi^{4} \cdot \theta - \frac{1}{12} \cdot \pi^{2} \cdot \theta^{2} + \frac{1}{12} \cdot \pi \cdot \theta^{3} - \frac{1}{48} \cdot \theta^{4}\\
&\dots\\
\end{align}
$$

These polynomials are theoretically solvable, but these relations are only special cases that only exist for natural indices. So that's a problem here too.

###### $3$ Fourier Series

Clausen functions can e.g. be used to regulate intuitively convergent Fourier Series. There are various formulas for this relationship that could perhaps be used here, but I don't know how.

###### $4$ Examples

I can invert some special cases by hand, e.g. these Polynomials form "Polynomial Clusters" (at least some of them). But that doesn't really get you any further to a general form now... Not even for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

###### $5$ Series Reversion

[Series Reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) failed 'cause of constant term.

EDIT:

It work's for a few series... But i don't know enogh.

Comment: You can use [Abelian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_formula) to invert any polynomial also for [$-v\in\Bbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130184/polylogarithms-of-negative-integer-order). Lagrange inversion or Fourier type series of the inverse of a non-elementary functions require finding $\int f^n(x) dx$. Maybe a recurrence relation for the coefficients can be found via differential equations.

Comment: I’m likely missing something, but as  things stand the series representations of $S_k(x)$ and $C_k(x)$ suggest these are odd and even functions, respectively, of $x$. The polynomials aren’t.

Comment: @Aruralreader Of course, you are right. These polynomials simply describe these clausen functions in a small interval: $I = \left[ 0,\, 2 \cdot \pi \right]$
Outside of this interval, they are no longer so similar. If you are interested:
Extensions for larger intervals also exist using the floor and ceil brackets / functions, but inverting them when chained seemed even more difficult to me. These generalizations then have the same symmetry properties as the Clausen functions for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

##### Not A Complete General Answer But A Patial Answer

With a while more research I have a publication on Clausen functions and formal power series expansions for Clausen functions. Namely [*On the closed form of Clausen functions* by *Slobodan B. Tričković* and *Miomir S. Miomir S. Stanković* (page $3$)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/368277037_On_the_closed_form_of_Clausen_functions).

> For $\alpha > 0$, the authors prove the formulas $[9]$
> $$ \begin{align*}
> S_{\alpha}\left( x \right) &= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\sin\left( n \cdot x \right)}{n^{\alpha}} \right] = \frac{\pi \cdot x^{\alpha - 1}}{2 \cdot \Gamma\left( \alpha \right) \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\alpha}{2} \right)} + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k} \cdot \zeta\left( \alpha - 2 \cdot k - 1 \right) \cdot x^{2 \cdot k + 1}}{\left( 2 \cdot k + 1 \right)!} \right]\\
> C_{\alpha}\left( x \right) &= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\cos\left( n \cdot x \right)}{n^{\alpha}} \right] = \frac{\pi \cdot x^{\alpha - 1}}{2 \cdot \Gamma\left( \alpha \right) \cdot \cos\left( \frac{\alpha}{2} \right)} + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k} \cdot \zeta\left( \alpha - 2 \cdot k \right) \cdot x^{2 \cdot k}}{\left( 2 \cdot k \right)!} \right]\\
> \end{align*} \tag{2.3}$$
> where $\zeta\left( s \right)$ is Riemann’s zeta function *[and $\Gamma\left( s \right)$ is the complete gamma function]*.

Note: I rewrote the formula minimally in the sense of my interpretation, since I use different parentheses.

We can apply the [Series Reversion Theory](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) to the power series expansion of $S_{\alpha}$ and thus form an inverse series expansion, but for this we first have to further restrict $\alpha$ to natural numbers larger than $1$ ($\alpha \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \left\{ 1 \right\}$), but then we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
S_{\alpha}^{-1}\left( x \right) &= \left( \frac{\pi}{2 \cdot \Gamma\left( \alpha \right) \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\alpha}{2} \right)} + A_{\left( k \in \mathbb{N}_{0} \setminus \left\{ \frac{\alpha - 2}{2} \right\} \right) + 1} \right) \cdot x^{\alpha - 1} + \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}_{0} \setminus \left\{ \frac{\alpha - 2}{2} \right\}}^{\infty}\left[ a_{2 \cdot k + 1} \cdot x^{2 \cdot k + 1} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $a_{k} = A_{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k \cdot A_{1}^{k}} \cdot \sum\limits_{s,\, t,\, u,\, \dots}\left[ \left( -1 \right)^{s + t + u + \dots} \cdot \frac{n \cdot \left( n + 1 \right) \cdots \left( n - 1 + s + t + u + \dots \right)}{s! \cdot t! \cdot u! \cdots } \cdot \left( \frac{A_{2}}{A_{1}} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{A_{3}}{A_{1}} \right) \cdots \right] \wedge s + 2 \cdot t + 3 \cdot u + \dots = k - 1$ and $A_{k}$ is the $k$th coefficient of the power series of $S_{\alpha}$. (this formula was found by *Morse* and *Feshbach*)

But that's still not really satisfying. As it is only true under very definite and severe restrictions. But it's something...

Comment: How complicated of an expression are you looking for?

Comment: @TymaGaidash There is no limit. It's all about the love of mathematics. But i would hope for an exact expression.